# Pretty way to show widget in list on condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to show/hide widget in a list depends on the condition.

All I have come up with is that:

```
return Row(
  children: [
    ...isLoading ? [CircularProgressIndicator()] : []
  ]
);
```

May you know a prettier way?

Answer (score 1):

for one child

```
return Row(
 children: [
   if(isLoading)   
     CircularProgressIndicator() , 
 ]
);
```

for many child try this

```
return Row(
  children: [
    if(isLoading) 
       ...[CircularProgressIndicator() ,CircularProgressIndicator()  ] ,  
  ]
);
```